# CDH 5.1 host IP address change

Tags: hadoop, ip-address, cloudera-cdh

I have a CDH 5.1 cluster with 3 nodes. We installed it using cloudera manager automated installation.
It was running perfect until we moved the box to a different network and IP addresses changed. I tried following steps

```
1. Stopped service, cloudera-scm-server.
2. Stopped service, cloudera-scm-agent
3. Edit the /etc/cloudera-scm-agent/config.ini
4. change the server host to the new ip.
5. restart service, cloudera-scm-agent, cloudera-scm-server.
```

not working .

Then i followed 
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-manager/v4-latest/Cloudera-Manager-Administration-Guide/cmag_change_hostnames.html
Not helped even after changing the ips in the PostgreSQL directly.

I found following blog : 
http://www.geovanie.me/changing-ip-of-node-in-cdh-cluster/

Getting following error in the scm-agent log file

```
ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for 127.0.0.1/RPC2: 401 Unauthorized>
```

Not working .... 
Can anyone please help how to change all IP addresses in a cdh 5.1 cluster safely .....

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: did you set anything in etc/hosts?

Comment: yes, I didfollowing is my hosts file look   127.0.0.1       localhost
113.128.152.38  txwlcloud1.dhcp.xxx.com
113.128.152.184 txwlcloud2.dhcp.xxx.com
113.128.152.197 txwlcloud3.dhcp.xxx.com

Comment: you should use domain names everywhere instead of ips

Answer (score 2):

This is causing because of precious cloudera-scm-agent service wasn't stopped correctly, please try,

```
$> ps -ef | grep supervisord
$> kill -9 <processID>
```

then restart the agent again.

```
$>service cloudera-scm-agent start
```